Implementing L2 Regularization in pure NumPy
I was implementing L2 Regularization in pure NumPy as an exercise to figure out the inner workings of the mathematics of an ML model.
I'm unsure if it's done well, I don't really have a reference to look off of.
I'm wondering if anyone is open to pointing any blatant mistakes in my code if any?
If you need more context, check out the full code at this github repo.
def mae(y, pred, lambd, w):
    eunorm = (lambd * ((np.sum(np.square(w))))) / y.size
    l = np.mean(np.abs((y - pred)))
    l = l + eunorm
    return eunorm, l

def mae_grad(y, pred):
    return - np.sign(y - pred)

def backwards(x, y, pred, eunorm):
    dz = mae_grad(y, pred)
    dw = (np.dot(dz, x.T) + ( 2 * eunorm)) / y.size
    db = np.sum(dz) / y.size
    return dw, db

